# Can a child have mother's surname?

Tags: halal-haram, children, naming

Im really confused .My daughter has her mother's surname since birth and  I  agreed to it. But I read online some sites are saying should fathers and others saying it doesn't matter aslong as identity of father is known to all . Shall she get my name added on when older or leave it as it is . Nothing in Quran about this topic